# How to exclude packages in sonar only for Cobertura but not for CheckStyle?

Tags: continuous-integration, sonarqube, findbugs, checkstyle, cobertura

We try to configure maven for run with sonar. At the moment sonar and maven in our project runs very well but now we try to exclude some packages of code coverage analysis.

It's possible to skip this packages only for code coverage but no for analysis of code with checkstyle?

We try this in our pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <instrumentation>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>com/gribas/web/**/*.class</exclude>
                        <exclude>com/gribas/web/**/*.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </instrumentation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

But doesn't run.

Anyone have an idea for do this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you used JaCoco as coverage engine in Sonar, then you'd be able to achieve what you want.

To use JaCoCo, set "sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin=jacoco".

And then, you can set exclusions with "sonar.jacoco.excludes=...".